# Why the promise is equal to "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, promise, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to create a simple loader that, when invoked, calls an API that return the data

```
requestData(pageSize, page, sorted, filtered){
    console.log(filtered);
    var url = `http://www.myurl.com/getProducts?start=${page*pageSize}&end=${page*pageSize+pageSize}`;
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
    r.onreadystatechange = function () {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200){
                reject(r);
            } else {
                resolve(r.responseText);
            }
        })
    };
    r.open("GET", url, true);
    r.send(null);
};

fetchData(state, instance) {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    this.requestData(
      state.pageSize,
      state.page,
      state.sorted,
      state.filtered
    ).then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.rows,
          pages: res.pages,
          loading: false
        });
    });
}
```

Both this function are in a React component. The problem is on the last .then() that is invoked on "undefined" object. Why my promise is not returned correctly?

Comment: `requestData` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3):

Cause you never return anything from `requestData`. You just return the promise *into* the callback function, which will go into nowhere. Instead of wrapping the promise into the callback, you should wrap the callback into the promise:

```
function  requestData(pageSize, page, sorted, filtered){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
     console.log(filtered);
     var url = `http://www.myurl.com/getProducts?start=${page*pageSize}&end=${page*pageSize+pageSize}`;
    var r = new XMLHttpRequest();

    r.onreadystatechange = function () {        
        if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200){
            reject(r);
        } else {
            resolve(r.responseText);
        }

    };
    r.open("GET", url, true);
    r.send(null);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because function `requestData` doesn't return anything. You have to return Promise object like this

```
requestData(pageSize, page, sorted, filtered){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(filtered);
        var url = `http://www.myurl.com/getProducts?start=${page*pageSize}&end=${page*pageSize+pageSize}`;
        var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
        r.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (r.readyState != 4 || r.status != 200){
                reject(r);
            } else {
                resolve(r.responseText);
            }
        }

        r.open("GET", url, true);
        r.send(null);
    });
}
```